# Laravel, Linux 2, Centos PostTooLargeException

Tags: laravel, centos

I have modified the php.ini to increase post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, memory_limit after using php -i | grep php.ini which returns the file location /etc/php.ini

After changing the settings the Apache server is restarted using sudo systemctl restart httpd. However, the error PostTooLargeException persists.

Is there a way to force an error message that will show why the error is persisting?

I have also seen some people saying to edit the .htaccess however my project shows 6 .htaccess files and I am not sure which one would need to be edited

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to force an error explaining what you want.

To debug it, you should create a php file which runs `phpinfo()` on your server:

```php
<?php
phpinfo()
```

There you can check your **post_max_size** and **upload_max_filesize** directives are correct.

Comment: The php.ini file is being read and the updated values are being used but continues to give the PostTooLarge error

Comment: What does it say beside those directives in phpinfo()?